# Is there an any way to pass data through export functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export, global-variables, state

```
export default function Example() { 
    const [name, setName] = useState(""); 
    return (<div>Example</div>);
}
```

I want to export {name}, because I will use it on another component. I just can do it with a global state (Context API or Redux), or there is a way to export var {name} which is rendered inside another export, easily?

Comment: _I just can do it with a global state (Context API or Redux)_ - That is how you should do it.

Comment: `useState()` hook is intended to manage _local_ state; if you need that variable in another non-child component as well, it means the information belongs to the state of a common ancestor or to the global state. Before looking for a way to export the variable, I'd recommend considering carefully whether it is correct to declare it where it is declared.

Comment: Read `context API` - https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `name` outside of an `Example` component tree (as a parent Component or somewhere else entirely), you'll need to either lift that state up to a higher common component, or use Context or Redux like you noted.